# How to get payment confirmation code with qiwi api?

Tags: python

How to get a payment confirmation code (which we usually get in the qiwi app on the phone) through qiwi api (requests python)? (shopping online)... And is it even real? Please give a couple of examples.

I couldn't find about it on the qiwi website ...